# Why isn't this square in the middle of the screen?

Tags: opengl, glulookat

I wrote some code, expecting to see a square in the middle of the screen, instead the square appears higher up, in some aspect ratios near the top of the screen, and slightly to the left.

[image: here's what's drawn on my screen]

With another aspect ratio:

[image: another example]

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
void resize(uint32_t height, uint32_t width){
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION); //set the matrix to projection
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 1000.0);
}


void draw(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //set up camera
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,10,0,0,0,0,0.001,0.999,0);

    //draw a square in the center of the screen
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor4f(0,1,1,1);
    glVertex3f(-1,0,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1,0,1);
    glVertex3f(1,0,1);
    glVertex3f(1,0,-1);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Isn't 0,0,0 supposed to be the middle of the screen? And isn't gluLookAt supposed to put whatever coordinate i specify in the center of the screen?

Comment: Use `gluLookAt()` carefully, if your view vector is colinear to your up vector (which is "almost" the case here) the transformation wont succeed. Adding some noise to your vector isn't a solution, you must check for colinearity yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind later. I tried setting the up vector to (0,0,1) instead, but I got the exact same result.

Comment: @bobbaluba - Are you certain you fixed the up vector correctly? I find it had to believe that it had no effect. Can you update your code with what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of `up` vector

```
gluLookAt(0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,1);
```

your eyes is at positive `y`-axis and reference point at center and `up` (head) vector must be along `z`-axis. 
You have done another mistake in your resize function

```
void resize(uint32_t height, uint32_t width){
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
.....................
gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 1000.0);
}
```

your variable `height` stores width of screen and variable `width` stores height, you have defined the `glViewport` and in `gluPerspective` you think your are taking ratio `width` by `height`, but actually you are taking ratio `height` by `width`, so it occurs the problem. Edit you code as follows:

```
void resize(uint32_t width, uint32_t height){
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
..................
gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 1000.0);
}
```

Comment: This is a valid *different* way to draw a quad, but this doesn't actually address his actual problem (why doesn't the code work). There's nothing wrong with pointing the camera along the y axis, as opposed to the z axis.

Comment: @Tim I think I found actual problem of code and I have edited my answer.

Comment: @DineshSmokin Yup, the problem was that the width and height was switched around. I feel kind of stupid that I posted it here, but I felt like I had tried everything.